# Preg_replace from a CMS db import that uses specific <tags>

Tags: php, regex, tags, pcre

I'm currently working on a website project I'm developping from start to scratch with a home-made content management system. The former website was running under SPIP (a french CMS) and I'm working to import the old content from the SPIP database on the new platform.

Things are running well, I'm getting all the articles, managed to code a new URL rewriting engine that keeps the old rewrited links as they were,..

The trouble I'm encountering is with the TEXT field of the articles that contains special tags. I did use str_replace to convert basic bbcode-like tags to html, but I'm encountering some troubles while trying to use preg_replace on more advanced tags.

Here is how the tag looks like. It's containted between plain text in a $texte var:

```
<doc30292|right>
```

As you see, the syntax looks like `<docID|alignment>`
I need to replace all the tags that looks like this by 
`display_doc($id,$alignment)`

I do manage to get the ID or the alignment using preg_match but I do want to use preg_replace and I do not know how to do this. PCRE isn't part of my strenghts...

Any help ?

```
$texte=nl2br($texte);
$texte=preg_replace('#(<br */?>\s*)+#i', '<br /><br/>', $texte);
    // SPIP Intertitre
$texte=str_replace("{{{","<h2>",$texte);
$texte=str_replace("}}}","</h2>",$texte);
// SPIP Gras
$texte=str_replace("{{","<b>",$texte);
$texte=str_replace("}}","</b>",$texte);
// SPIP Italic
$texte=str_replace("{","<i>",$texte);
$texte=str_replace("}","</i>",$texte);
preg_match('/<doc(.*?)\|/', $texte, $match);
var_dump($match);
echo $match[1];
```

Comment: Well, post your code so far and we certainly can help...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$subject = '<doc30292|right>';
$pattern = '/<([^|]+)\|([^>]+)>/';

if (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $tokens)) {
  list($_, $id, $alignment) = $tokens;
  echo sprintf('display_doc(%s, %s)', $id, $alignment);
}
```

For this I get the output `display_doc(doc30292, right)`.

---

As for replacing multiple occurrences, as mentioned in your comment below, I would use the more convenient `preg_replace_callback()` function:

```
<?php

$subject = 'dumbo<doc4711|left>bla<doc30292|right>blub<doc666|center>lamda';
$pattern = '/<([^|]+)\|([^>]+)>/';

echo preg_replace_callback(
    $pattern, 
    function ($_) { return sprintf('display_doc(%s,%s)',$_[1],$_[2]); }, 
    $subject);
```

This obviously returns: `dumbodisplay_doc(doc4711,left)bladisplay_doc(doc30292,right)blubdisplay_doc(doc666,center)lamda`

Comment: Thanks for helping, sir !
It works well, unless it does work only for the first occurence. Is there a way doing it with preg_replace ?

Comment: Again, thanks ! But i'm still facing issues, sadly :( First of all, only two of the <doc> tags are replaced correctly, but not in the place they belong in the string: they are moved at the top of the string. I don't get why. (This is a huge string extracted from database containing a 1000words+ article)

Comment: Sorry, there is nothing I can say to this. You have to post your string and your current script. I suggest you make a new question for that specific problem...

Comment: I fixed this !! Thanks ! :) I was using the code in a wrong way ;)